# How can I say that all elements in an array must have some property in OCL?

Tags: uml, ocl

I have the following class:

[image]

and I would like to express in OCL the following constraint:

*Every String in pre must either contain ('not' and one ' ') or contain no ' '*

is it possible? How can I write it? 
Thank you!!

P.s. By writing ' ' I mean a whitespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've done a fairly good job of using formal English so transliteration to OCL is now easy. But you have used List<> which is not a UML or OCL facility, so without providing its operations who knows? I therefore assume you use some form of Collection, possibly Sequence. (In UML you get Collections automnatically by specifying an uopper bound greater than 1.)

Ideally you could transliterate to:

```
pre->forAll(s |
  (s.contains('not') and (s.count(' ') = 1)) or (s.count(' ') = 0))
```

but standard OCL has no String::contains() or String:::count() so we'll have to work a bit harder. Eclipse OCL has String::tokenize(), String:lastIndexOf() and String::matches() any of which could be used. But in Standard OCL, we probably have to resort to characters() to create a Sequence of String each containing one character.

```
For s.contains('not') use s.indexOf('not') >= 0
For s.count(' ') use s.characters->count(' ')
```

and to avoid evaluating s.characters->count(' ') twice on a poor OCL tool, introduce a let variable.

Comment: I'm not to deep in OCL, but what I understand from your answer is that OCL depends on some implementation (here Eclipse). I thought there's a "standard" from OMG.

Comment: Reread my answer. I clearly state that the final answer is for standard OCL.

Comment: Yes. But I interpret the first part that there can be implementations which offer non-standard stuff like the `String::tokenize()`.

Comment: @EdWillink I have modified the UML diagram of the class. In this way I should get a collection and the constraint written in standard OCL should work, shouldn't it? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ThomasKilian. The OMG OCL specification is unfortunately very far from perfect, so tool vendors must do their best to make sense of it. Eclipse OCL prototypes some resolutions introducing a clear distinction between OCL language and OCL standard library, which of course can be usefully extended.